# Does anyone know a good pastebin where I can easily pickup the code with curl?

Tags: curl, paste

I'm in a domU with nothing but a console to work with an internet connection.

I need to configure a file in it that I feel is too long to just type by hand.
So I want to pick it up from somewhere else instead.

The first and only thing that has come up to me is pastebin + curl, but I don't know any pastebins that show it's pastes naked. 
There's always html stuff surrounding it.

Comment: As currently posed, this doesn't seem much like a U&L question.

Comment: First of all, I agree with @MichaelHomer that this Q is off-topic phrased as it is. But I recognise your problem and my solution in those cases was to use netcat.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ has a download link on each page.  It also has a raw data field which you can highlight and 'Select All' and then 'Copy'.  Then paste into a text editor on your domU.  Neither of these features even requires javascript to work, which is nice.

Comment: I apologize for posting this as a U&L question. Is there any way I can move this question? I also was not aware of the raw option in pastebin.com, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: Okay, I just flagged it to move to stack overflow.

Comment: This would be completely off topic on SO as well. It's actually a better fit here. Just [edit] and explain what you are doing in a bit more detail. What do you mean by "configure a file"? What exactly would you have in the pastebin? The file's name? Its contents? Show us the commands you need to run and we should be ab;e to offer a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Bitbucket snippets](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/03/18/snippets-for-teams-are-here-with-a-rich-set-of-apis/): from the link, scroll to heading=`Rich set of APIs`. That links to, e.g., `curl`-based API to [put a snippet](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/snippets-endpoint-719095086.html#snippetsEndpoint-POSTanewsnippet) and [get a snippet](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/snippets-endpoint-719095086.html#snippetsEndpoint-GETaspecificsnippet).